# Select data from different object in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am still new to the LINQ thing, and am having some trouble. I think this is all messed up but I have a model that contains several properties, and object of a different type (Project). I get an error: Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'string'. I want to be able to select the ProjectId and ProjectName from the ProjectModel object that is reference in my NotificationModel Object. This is what I have but this doesnt work, how can I change this to correctly grab the information from the ProjectModel object?

Notification Model:

```
public int id { get; set; }
public int ProjectId { get; set; }
public string ProjectName { get; set; }
[StringLength(50)]
public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
public Nullable<bool> IsDeleted { get; set; 

public virtual ProjectModel Project { get; set; }
```

Trying to retrieve Data:

```
        var notifications = (from a in db.NotificationsLog
                            where a.CreatedBy == userID
                            orderby a.CreatedDateTime ascending
                            select new NotificationModel
                            {
                                id = a.id,
                                ProjectId =  from p in db.Projects
                                          select new
                                                    {
                                                        ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                                                    }
                                ProjectName = from p in db.Projects
                                          select new

                                                    {
                                                        ProjectName = p.ProjectName
                                                    }
                                Notes = a.Notes;
                            });
```

Comment: What isn't working, are you getting an error or just not what you expected?

Comment: How is `db.NotificationsLog` related to `db.Projects`? do you really want to do a cross-join?

Comment: Is you using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)?

Comment: @p.s.w.g Notifications contains a list of well notifications related to a project. What other way could I do it without a join? The projectId is stored in the Notification object, and then I need to pull out the project information to display to it.

Comment: @ios85 Do you have a navigation property on `Notification -> Project`?

Comment: You need to associate projects to notifications somehow, in your query you are getting all projectids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a navigation property on your `Notification` entity to `Project`, you can just do this:

```
var notifications = 
    (from a in db.NotificationsLog
     let p = a.Project
     where a.CreatedBy == userID
     orderby a.CreatedDateTime ascending
     select new NotificationModel
     {
         id = a.id,
         ProjectId = p.Id,
         ProjectName = p.Name,
         Project = new ProjectModel
         {
             ProjectId = p.Id
             ProjectName = p.Name
             Notes = a.Notes;
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var notifications = from a in db.NotificationsLog
                    join p in db.Projects on a.ProjectId equals p.ProjectId
                    where a.CreatedBy == userID
                    select new NotificationModel
                            {
                                id = a.id,
                                ProjectId = p.ProjectId,
                                ProjectName = p.ProjectName,
                                Notes = a.Notes
                            };
```